# how to create tryCatch extension function

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-extension

i like to achieve this kind of code:

```
someKindOfCode.tryCatch()
```

i kind of created it but Any doesn't do the job and don't put the code inside of tryCatch

```
private fun Any.tryCatch() {
    try {
        this
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e(TAG, "tryCatch: ", e)
    }
 }
```

Comment: Could you provide example on how do you want to use it? With real code and not `someKindOfCode` variable. Generally speaking, `someKindOfCode` would need to be one of executable types like: function type, Java `Function`, `Runnable`, `Callable`, etc. But usually we don't use extensions in cases like this. Regular function is better, especially with Kotlin syntactic sugar for higher-order functions. See for example `runCatching()`.

Comment: by some kind of code i mean something like a Function that i don't want to manually declare try catch for it and i just want to call a function like .tryCatch() after it and it would automatically put it in try catch with my TAG.

Comment: Yes, I understand what do you try to achieve. I'm only not sure, how do you want to use it in your code. As explained by @Evansgelist below, you can do: `{ myFunction(1, 2, 3) }.tryCatch()` or `tryCatch { myFunction(1, 2, 3) }`. The latter is much more Kotlin-ish.  If these solutions do not suit you then I'm not sure what is your expected typical usage. Note `myFunction(1, 2, 3).tryCatch()` is not possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can declare functions outside the class and use wherever you want

```
fun <T> tryCatch(block: () -> T) =
    try {
        block()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
```

example using

```
class Test {

    fun testFun() {
        tryCatch {
            val res = 9 / 2
            res * 5
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
another option, but it looks a little strange

```
fun <T> (() -> T).tryCatch() =
    try {
        this()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
```

example

```
class Test {
    fun testFun() = {
        val res = 9 / 2
        res * 5
    }.tryCatch()
}
```

Comment: nice job , but i wrote this function my self too but i kinda don't want to put my code in a block like this tryCatch {}

Comment: Added another option. But try to understand, you cannot call an extension function just for a piece of code. You must have some kind of class